# How do I make it so that if I click an <a> element it goes to the link, but it doesn't trigger the .click() event of its parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to click on a particular `<a>` and activate the link out, but not the parent's click.

`preventDefault()` doesn't work because then it won't link out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling.

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

~from jQuery docs [**.stopPropagation**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `stopPropagation` instead of `preventDefault`

```
$('a').click(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```